# Load CSV file from within docker container to PostgresSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, airflow

I'm trying to create an Airflow pipeline that downloads data from an API, processes it, saves it as a CSV and then loads the data to a Postgres database (all within a docker container).
The code looks something like this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "retries": 5,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1),
    "email": ['airflow@domain.com'],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": False
}

def get_data():
    request = request.get("some_url")
    request_data = request.json()
    all_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(request_data["data"])
    all_data.to_csv("/opt/airflow/data/all_data.csv",index=False)

with DAG( 
    dag_id="my_dag", 
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2022,1,24),
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5)
) as dag:
    create_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="create_table",
        postgres_conn_id="postgres_localhost",
        sql="""
        create table if not exists my_table(
            created_at timestamp,
            col1 double precision,
            col2 smallint,
            primary key (created_at, col1)
        )
        """
    )

    get_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id="get_data", 
        python_callable=get_data
    )

    load_data = PostgresOperator(
        task_id = "load_data",
        postgres_conn_id="postgres_localhost",
        sql="""
        copy my_table
        from '/opt/airflow/data/all_data.csv'
        delimiter ',' csv;
        """

    )

create_table >> get_data >> load_data
```

The problem is that when I try to run the DAG I get an error in the `load_data` task saying `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not open file "/opt/***/data/all_data.csv" for reading: No such file or directory HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.`

I don't know why the word `airflow` is getting replaced in the path or how to save it properly so that the CSV file can be copied into postgres.

Comment: Are you sure that a file exists at `/opt/airflow/data/all_data.csv`, and that your script has permission to read it? (About the "***" in the path, my best guess is that that's just how the path was truncated for the error message, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: I think the asterisks are a security feature, given that the airflow db password is 'airflow'.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the postgres server is a separate instance within Docker. You could try one of the following ways around this:

1. Copy the file between servers by using using `scp` to place the data file onto the postgres server
2. Copy the file between servers by using SFTPOperator (which requires SSH Hook instatiation), then do the COPY statement.
3. Connect manually to the Postgres db via the BashOperator and run the copy CLI command for Postgres.

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please answer. I have this same problem right now and am working on it. Once I have it, I'll post it back here.